# How to notify when the sd card has been removed or reinsert in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to check when the SD Card has been removed or reinserted in Cocoa app. How can I do that? I tried use the following code but it shows error:

```
    static void diskAppearedCallback(DADiskRef disk, void* context)
{
    CFDictionaryRef description = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
    NSLog(@"Disk appeared: %@", description);
    CFRelease(description);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(session, kDADiskDescriptionMatchVolumeMountable, diskAppearedCallback, 0);
    DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(session, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    return 0;
}
```

And this is an error:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_DADiskCopyDescription", referenced from:
      _diskAppearedCallback in TestAppDelegate.o
  "_DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback", referenced from:
      -[TestAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in TestAppDelegate.o
  "_DASessionCreate", referenced from:
      -[TestAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in TestAppDelegate.o
  "_DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[TestAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in TestAppDelegate.o
  "_kDADiskDescriptionMatchVolumeMountable", referenced from:
      -[TestAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in TestAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to add the `DiskArbitration.framework` in your Target's properties.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I missed add this framework. thanks